# Why does the Chief Engineer of DS9 have an office on the promenade?

Tags: star-trek-ds9, space-station

In the [list of establishments on the Terrok DS9 promenade](http://www.lcars.org.uk/lcars_a218.htm) we find the "Chief Engineer's Office" at 01-409.

Why would the station's Chief Engineer have an office on the promenade? Does he really? I don't recall seeing such an office, or engineers going in or out of it. We know O'Brien is the top technical person on the station - basically, as a commenter points out, he's Chief of Operations. Does DS9 even have a Chief Engineer? If it does, how come they never meet, and O'Brien does whatever he wants with all station systems?

Is this maybe the equivalent of "Cetacean operations" on the Enterprise-D?

Comment: I believe this to be the Chief of [mining] Engineering. Note that there's also a Geological Assay Office and a Mining Corporation

Comment: You may also want to note that O'Brien isn't the station's Chief Engineer, he's their Chief of Operations.

Comment: @Valorum: Interesting. References? Anyway, edited my answer according to your second comment.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rY94.png

Comment: He probably promised himself he’d set up his office once he’d fixed all the major issues with the station, and just never got there.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - And demoted himself at the same time?

Comment: @Valorum: I meant, references to the Chief Engineer being the Chief _Mining_ Engineer... I know what O'Brien is :-P

Comment: Given that the station has commercial and residential tenants, it would be nice for them to have somewhere to go and complain when the heating or water isn't working.

Comment: @Cadence: That would be the "Utilities service desk", not the "Chief Engineer's office"...